# SQL Server returning weird affected row counts on simple query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

In certain databases for a while update queries have stopped returning sensible affected row counts. This is not the case for other databases on this server. I would do something simple like

```
update calendaritems set isdeleted = 1 where startdate = '2016-01-01 9:00' and contactid = 5
```

and it returns this:

```
(12 row(s) affected)

(12 row(s) affected)
#289#

(532 row(s) affected)

(6 row(s) affected)

(24 row(s) affected)

(12 row(s) affected)
```

The 12s would be correct, no idea why they're printed three times and why there's other affected row counts, let alone the hashtag number.

SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2

Comment: Trigger effect ;)

Comment: My guess is that your update might be firing a trigger on the table, and the excessive output is the trigger processing and output.

Comment: Updating that one table, causes 5 other tables to get updated.  There must be triggers in your tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most Probably there are triggers defined for any "update" on table "calendaritems". So please verify those triggers to understand the SQL commands in them. That will give information about all the other ResultSet counts that you are getting under message window.